# How to turn my PCs into a wired router?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

Why do I need to turn my PC's into a router ?
I need to connect my Philips lights to Philips Bridge, and my Philips Bridge to the Philips app.

The Philips Bridge has a power and an Ethernet port as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

I don't have any router at home, I have a wireless router with no Ethernet port on it, something similar to Wimax, it's temporary since I just moved in.

What do I have ?

-Two PCs: one Mac and one Windows laptop.
-A switch
-Thunderbolt and USB adapters
-Countless Ethernet cables
-Wimax modem

What I have already tried?

A lots of videos on Youtube of course.

I connected my Philips Bridge to my Mac, via an Ethernet cable to my Thunderbolt adapter, see the picture below:

[image]

Then I turned on internet sharing on my Mac:

[image]

And I configured the IP address manually, since DHCP only gives me the 169. ... address. I choose a different IP address for the Bridge than my own Mac of course:

[image]

Now all the three blue lights on my bridge are on, which according to the manual is the required condition to get connected to the app, also my phone, Mac and the Bridge are all connected to the same network.

[image]

But the app doesn't find the Bridge, I think there is something I did wrong, or it's pretty impossible to create a virtual router!

And I did the same to my Windows laptop: still not working.

Update:
When I share my Mac internet to my other laptop, it works, however when I replace the port with the Bridge, it goes to self assigned IP 169. .....

Comment: Your Mac is sharing its internet connection, but not its connection to the rest of your home LAN. That's how IS works. idk how you get around that without a router that can use ethernet.

Comment: @Tetsujin I see, what do you mean by IS ?

Comment: Internet Sharing

Comment: @SamB Have you seen [How To Connect Hue Bridge Without Ethernet Cable](https://robotpoweredhome.com/hue-bridge-without-ethernet/)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes :), too risky to do it and I might loos the warranty. The other methode requires a new AP, which I don't have